# Maximum value of $z_1^2 + z_2^2$ subject to conditions.

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $z_1$ and $z_2$ be two complex numbers such that
$$\begin{eqnarray}
z_1(z_1^2-3z_2^2)&=&2\tag{i}\\
z_2(3z_1^2-z_2^2)&=&1\tag{ii}
\end{eqnarray}$$

If it is given that $k=z_1^2+z_2^2$ is a real number, then what is the value of $k$?

---

(I have absolutely no idea how to proceed.)

Comment: Are you trying to find the value of $z_1^2+z_2^2$ or the maximum possible value? If the maximum, then you would need to define what $>$ means between two complex numbers.  Or is the fact that  $z_1^2+z_2^2$ is real a third constraint?

Comment: @MarkFischler I am trying to find the (only possible) value of the $z_1^2+z_2^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

$$2+i=z_1^3+3z_1^2(iz_2)+3z_1(iz_2)^2+(iz_2)^3=(z_1+iz_2)^3$$

$$ 2-i=?$$

$$(2-i)(2+i)=?$$

Comment: ␚␚␚␚␚␚␚␚THANKS␚␚␚␚␚␚␚␚